# Custom Settings.bundle - How to call method from app in Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, web-services, settings.bundle

Trying to call a method that check webservices connection in Settings app on iPhone. 
Is it possible to call a method implemented in .m files from Settings app in ios device?

How to solve the problem?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. But search for Reachability, maybe that is what you are looking for